# How to generate password hash for kong?

Tags: lua, kong, resty

I'm using kong in serverless mode and it seems that in this mode password has to show up as an hashcode.
In this [topic](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/4542) they say how to generate one using lua but I have no idea on how to execute this thing on my machine.

Any idea or equivalent one?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: they suggested a very complicated way.
The password is just a sha1 calculated by concatenating the password with a generated uuid.
I used online tools to generate my password